# Filter object by a value of child array

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Say I want to select all research_report-published results containing values for algorithm "Autoencoder" or "Boosted Regression trees" or both

[image]
[image]

For matching all filters I have idea like this:

Add a new field `algorithms-cancatinated` (with sorted and concatinated strings of all values in algorithms array ) e.g storing `Autoencoder,Boosted Regression,Long Short-Term Memory` for first object and `Autoencoder,Boosted Regression` for 2nds one, then on that field do exact match like this

```
constructor(private afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {}
this.afDb.list(`research_reports-published/`).orderby(algorithms-cancatinated).StartAt(`Autoencoder,Boosted Regression`).EndAt(`Autoencoder,Boosted Regression`);
```

But I can not do "Autoencoder" or "Boosted Regression trees" here

I am using angularfire2.

Comment: Do you have any code right now? What have you tried so far?

Comment: ```constructor(private afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {}this.afDb.list(`research_reports-published/`);```

Comment: the only idea I have is to add a new field, with sorted and concatinated strings of all values in algorithms array then on that field do exact match it using orderby(algorithms-cancatinated).StartAt(concatinated string value).EndAt(concatinated string value). Looking for ways to do it without changing any db node